# SQL Server Database Suspect with Memory table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

Today my database seems suspect. I am running SQL Server 2016 with memory tables. The below code won't work to fix the suspect. SQL Server keeps saying I have to restore. Any ideas?

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus dbname;
ALTER DATABASE dbnameSET EMERGENCY
 DBCC checkdb(dbname)
ALTER DATABASE dbnameSET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

 DBCC CheckDB (dbname, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE dbnameSET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: Well... https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/run-dbcc-checkdb-memory-oltp-hekaton-tables/

Comment: At this point, you've essentially nuked everything with repair_allow_data_loss so I wouldn't put any more time into it TBH. Restore from your backups... I hope they don't have any corruption in them.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, [corruption checking doesn't work for In-Memory OLTP (Hekaton)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/run-dbcc-checkdb-memory-oltp-hekaton-tables/).

Your best bet is to restore from backup at this point, and then maybe [upvote the request for Microsoft to get corruption checking to work](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902300-dbcc-checkdb-needs-to-check-the-checksums-on-in-me). Maybe someday you'll be able to check for corruption on your important data before you're stuck getting surprised like this.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with **Sean Gallardy**. Restore from the updated backup. Read more about suspect database mode from here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/